# What jdk should I use?

Tags: java, version

Are more consumers using Java 6, or Java 7 now?

I want to develop an app that will reach the most users. However, I'm concerned that if I use JDK 7 it won't work on many peoples' computers because they will have an outdated JRE.

Is there any data on the percentage of people that use each JRE? Like the (out-of-date) data found here:  [What Java versions are commonly installed on browsers, is it safe to assume 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650582/what-java-versions-are-commonly-installed-on-browsers-is-it-safe-to-assume-1-4)

This would be a standalone desktop app.

Comment: People with even two week old java are using insecure software, http://java-0day.com/

Comment: I think, in general, most people are settled on 1.6.  1.7 is current, with 1.8 being promised soon.  If you want to get the maximum possible compatibility, shoot for 1.5.  Keep in mind you can compile on a 1.6/1.7, but have your IDE (at least Eclipse) set to 1.5 dialect and rules.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, that can be said for any software, not just JVMs.

Comment: Is there any raw data on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [stat owl](http://www.statowl.com/java.php) most of the users who have a Java plugin in the browser do *not* have JVM7. You can ship JVM7 with your application if it's a desktop app.

If you're building for the desktop you should not be concerned about this.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what kind of application you're building. If you're creating an applet, you might want to reconsider using an applet. Almost anything that an applet can do is faster and safer with HTML5/Javascript. A lot of safety issues come from the JRE browser plugin so it tends to be disabled more and more these days. If you're building a desktop application i should always go with the latest JRE. Same goes for server-side Java.

Also, Java 6 is EOL since february this year so you shoudnt use that anymore.

Comment: "If you're creating an applet, please stop and use HTML and Javascript for that." - While I generally agree with this statement, I think it's somewhat controversial. Would you mind phrasing it in a way that seems more objective

Comment: Good point. I edited it to be a bit more helpful :)

Comment: Java Applets won't even run at all in some browsers (e.g., Chrome on Mac).

Comment: That's because the JRE plugin is disabled by default. If you install/enable it an applet should work. But you shouldn't do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not really telling us on what are you planning to do.

Do you want to programm a stand alone application, a web application or an applet?

For the stand alone application I would probably go for java 6 and make sure it is working with java 7 as well.

For the Web Application the Java runs server side so you can ignore what the user has.

I wouldn't write an applet if not really necessary. Users tend to disable their browser plugins at the moment for security reasons and they seem to be a little bit dated anyways.

Comment: Stand alone application

Answer (score 0):

You can deliver the JDK with your app if you are building a desktop app, and building a browser based Java app is probably not a good choice right now no matter what version.

Answer (score 0):

If you writing a client application i would go with java 5 because you are compatible with the most JVM's and have a good feature set from java. Java 5 introduced generics and annotations which makes the programming much easier and the code safer. Java6 and Java7 introduces small features. When Java8 comes out it will be a big hit because of lambda, new date api etc.

If you develop a server-side/enterprise application i would go with the latest stable java release because it will make your application faster, easier maintainable and you can use the latest frameworks.